# Bootstrap & Jquery Modal Window - Actualizar contenido

Tags: php, jquery, json, bootstrap, modal

estoy creando una sitio web en el cual al clicar en un botón se abre una ventana Modal donde muestra una serie de imágenes.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En cada una de esas imágenes hay los botones descargar y borrar.

Al hacer clic en borrar no sé como hacer desaparecer esa imagen, es decir que recargue el contenido del modal.

El código jquery:

```
    $('.btn-image-library').click(function() {

        var cod = $('#editCodi').val();
        var src = $( this ).closest('.box-image-library').find('.image-library').attr('src');
        var action = $( this ).text();
        var filename = $( this ).closest('.box-image-library').find('.text-descripcio-image-library').text();

        if (action == 'delete'){

            // Delete image
            $.ajax({
                url:"deleteImagesManageProduct.php",
                type:"POST",
                data:{"filename": filename, "codigo": cod},
                dataType:"text",
                success:function(data){
                    // AQUÍ ACTUALIZAR CONTENIDO MODAL ¿?
                }
            });

        }
    });
```

El código HTML de la ventana Modal:

```
    <!-- MANAGE IMAGES MODAL MENU -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="manageImagesProduct" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="change" aria-hidden="true">

      <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">

           <div class="modal-content">

                  <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Gestió Imatges</h3>
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-body">
                      <div class="">
                          <?php
                          //  Load Images
                          $query = "SELECT t1.num, t1.imagen
                                    FROM imatges AS t1
                                    WHERE t1.codigo = '{$_GET['cod']}'
                                    ORDER BY t1.num";

                          $result = dbQuery($conn, $query);

                          while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){
                              ?>
                              <div class="box-image-library">

                                  <img class="image-library" src='<?php echo $row[1];?>' id='fileImage'/>

                                  <div class="btn-image-library-delete">
                                      <button class='btn-image-library' id='deleteImage'><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">delete</i></button>
                                      <button class='btn-image-library' id='downloadImage'><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">file_download</i></button>
                                  </div>

                                  <div class="box-text-image-library">
                                      <span class="text-descripcio-image-library"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></span>
                                  </div>

                              </div>
                              <?php
                          }
                          ?>
                      </div>
                  </div>

                  <div class="modal-footer " >
                      <div class="pull-right">
                          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-gral btn-tool-footer-medium btn-icon" id='btnManageImagesAdd' value="Afegir">
                          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-gral btn-tool-footer-medium btn-icon" id='btnManageImagesSelect' value="Seleccionar">
                          <input type="submit" class="btn btn-gral btn-tool-footer-medium btn-icon" id='btnManageImagesFinalitzar' style="background-color: #73CBB0; color:black;" value="Finalitzar">
                      </div>
                  </div>
          </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Os agradecería cualquier tipo de ayuda en este sentido.

Muchas Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una opción es que cargues las imágenes con un id (supongo que es en num). El los botones de borrar y de descargar pones `data-idImagen` y le asignas el mismo valor que el id de la imagen. Ya tienes una forma de relacionarlos. Ahora, en el código de javascript, recuperas el data-id y lo pones en la variable `idImagen`. Y en el `success` de ajax pones el selector por id y la asignas el método `.remove()`.

Tienes el código a continuación:

**Javascript**

```
  $('.btn-image-library').click(function () {
        var idImagen = $(this).data().idImagen
        var cod = $('#editCodi').val();
        var src = $(this).closest('.box-image-library').find('.image-library').attr('src');
        var action = $(this).text();
        var filename = $(this).closest('.box-image-library').find('.text-descripcio-image-library').text();
        if (action == 'delete') {

            // Delete image
            $.ajax({
                url: "deleteImagesManageProduct.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: {"filename": filename, "codigo": cod},
                dataType: "text",
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#" + idImagen).remove()
                    // AQUÍ ACTUALIZAR CONTENIDO MODAL ¿?
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<!-- MANAGE IMAGES MODAL MENU -->

    <div class="modal fade" id="manageImagesProduct" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="change" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Gestió Imatges</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <div class="">
                    <?php
                    //  Load Images
                    $query = "SELECT t1.num, t1.imagen
                                    FROM imatges AS t1
                                    WHERE t1.codigo = '{$_GET['cod']}'
                                    ORDER BY t1.num";

                    $result = dbQuery($conn, $query);

                    while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){
                    ?>
                    <div class="box-image-library">

                        <img class="image-library" src='<?php echo $row[1];?>' id='<?php echo $row['num'];?>'/>

                        <div class="btn-image-library-delete">
                            <button class='btn-image-library' id='deleteImage' data-idImagen='<?php echo $row['num'];?>'><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">delete</i>
                            </button>
                            <button class='btn-image-library' id='downloadImage' data-idImagen='<?php echo $row['num'];?>'><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">file_download</i>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="box-text-image-library">
                            <span class="text-descripcio-image-library"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></span>
                        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que dibujaste las imágenes directamente vía PHP, una solución sencilla seria agregándole un ID a cada contenedor de imagen al momento de dibujar.

Hare una pequeña suposición que `row[0]` devuelve el id de la fila o clave primaria, modificando el codigo un poco quedaria.

```
<?php
//  Load Images
$query = "SELECT t1.num, t1.imagen
        FROM imatges AS t1
        WHERE t1.codigo = '{$_GET['cod']}'
        ORDER BY t1.num";

$result = dbQuery($conn, $query);

while ($row = pg_fetch_row($result)){
    ?>
    <div class="box-image-library" id="img_<?php echo $row[0];?>">

        <img class="image-library" src='<?php echo $row[1];?>' id='fileImage'/>

        <div class="btn-image-library-delete">
            <button class='btn-image-library' id='deleteImage' onClick="borrarImagen('<?php echo $row[0];?>', '<?php echo $row[1];?>')"><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">delete</i></button>
            <button class='btn-image-library' id='downloadImage'><i class="material-icons" style="font-size: 20px">file_download</i></button>
        </div>

        <div class="box-text-image-library">
            <span class="text-descripcio-image-library"><?php echo $row[1]; ?></span>
        </div>

    </div>
    <?php
}
?>
```

luego la función borrar, modificada un poco quedaría así:

```
function borrarImagen(id, path) {
    let cod = $('#editCodi').val();
    let filename = path;
    $.ajax({
        url:"deleteImagesManageProduct.php",
        type:"POST",
        data:{"filename": filename, "codigo": cod},
        dataType:"text",
        success:function(data){
            $(`img_${id}`).remove();
        }
    });
}
```

En fin con esto queda, y se puede quitar el html usando [$.remove()](https://api.jquery.com/remove/) según tu aproximación también también puede buscar el `div` padre pero me parece engorroso.